# How do I make this popup dont show up behind main header

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello first of all I'd like to thank you for your time in advance.

Im trying to build my first website and I’m stuck with a pop showing behind my header on desktop.

On the checkout page I have a payment option “Paga con Yape o Plin” when the user selects it and clicks on “Realizar pedido” or place order a popup is triggered (popup-main-wrapper) so the user can scan the QR code. The problem is this pop-up is showing behind the header and I cant seem to center it on the screen.

- [Issue](https://ibb.co/QFY0YfM)
- I want to make it look like [this:](https://ibb.co/sjJB1HS)

My site url: https://intiwallets.com/checkout/

Edit:
Im sorry forgot to mention, I did try this code on the popup-wrapper adjusting the height to 115%, looked good but when I looked at it on a different PC and browser It was still showing up behind the header.

```
.popup-wrapper{
background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
/*cursor:pointer;*/
display:none;
height:115%;
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:10000;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Have a good day
Christian,

Comment: Stackoverflow is basically a website for:
- I have tried this (put some code) and I got this. What can I do to have that ?
Please show us some code attempts.

Comment: As the comment above says, please read the 'How to Ask' help page [ask] - Mainly the 'Help others reproduce the problem` section

Comment: Im sorry about that, I added the code I modified that kinda worked but still showed up behind the header when browsing from another PC / browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your popup just needs a bit of margin on top, so it gets a little lower and doesn't disappear behind your header. Try adding this to you `popup-wrapper`:

```
margin-top:100px;
```